# Truncate HBase table via REST interface

Tags: hbase

Like the question says: Is it possible to truncate an hbase table via the REST interface? Looking at the docs (http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest), there seems to be no documented or direct commands for this. But it seems like this would a relatively common use case. Does anyone know a nice way to implement this kind of function using only REST commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is supported and you should avoid using truncate on HBase tables except for development or testing purpose.
If you really need to purge rows, check if the TTL can fulfill your needs (see https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ttl)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why truncating should be avoided (new to hbase)?

Comment: First of all HBase is a clone of Google Big Table and as such designed to store large volumes of data. If you use HBase to store big volumes, there is no reason to drop everything at some stage (unless your data expires in which case use DDL). The second reason is related to HBase internal mechanisms (data distribution, compaction mechanism, region splits) which “do not like” truncates. We had major problems in production with an application using truncates.